# How to replace multiple strings with replace() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, replace, split

I'm guessing this is a simple problem, but I'm just learning...

I have this:

```
var location = (jQuery.url.attr("host"))+(jQuery.url.attr("path"));
locationClean = location.replace('/',' ');

locationArray = locationClean.split(" ");

console.log(location);
console.log(locationClean);
console.log(locationArray);
```

And here is what I am getting in Firebug:

```
stormink.net/discussed/the-ideas-behind-my-redesign
stormink.net discussed/the-ideas-behind-my-redesign
["stormink.net", "discussed/the-ideas-behind-my-redesign"]
```

So for some reason, the replace is only happening once? Do I need to use Regex instead with "/g" to make it repeat? And if so, how would I specifiy a '/' in Regex? (I understand very little of how to use Regex).

Thanks all.

Comment: Shit! I got it right after I asked... sorry everyone! Won't happen again... (hopefully).

Comment: Then answer your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replace method only replaces the first occurance when you use a string as the first parameter. You have to use a regular expression to replace all occurances:

```
locationClean = location.replace(/\//g,' ');
```

(As the slash characters are used to delimit the regular expression literal, you need to escape the slash inside the excpression with a backslash.)

Still, why are you not just splitting on the '/' character instead?

Answer (score 5):

Use a pattern instead of a string, which you can use with the "global" modifier

```
locationClean = location.replace(/\//g,' ');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could directly [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) using the `/` character as the separator:

```
var loc =  location.host + location.pathname, // loc variable used for tesing
    locationArray = loc.split("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed from your javascript.

**SYNTAX**

```
stringObject.replace(findstring,newstring)
```

> *findstring:* Required. Specifies a string value to find. To perform a global search add a 'g' flag to this parameter and to perform a case-insensitive search add an 'i' flag.
>
> *newstring:* Required. Specifies the string to replace the found value from findstring

Here's what ur code shud look like:

```
locationClean = location.replace(new RegExp('/','g'),' ');
locationArray = locationClean.split(" ");
```

njoi'